# How do I get Route attribute to work in .net core api?

Tags: asp.net-core

So I added a controller to a blank asp.net CORE Api.

```
    public class IsAliveController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("isalive")]
        public object Get()
        {
    
            return "I'm alive";
        }
    }
```

Then I try to access it via https://localhost:44361/isalive
and I get no response. Do I need to make some modifications to my Startup.cs?

Answer (score 0):

First why have you declared your method both as a get and a post request? you can remove the post attribute.

By default your routing must start with your controller name, add this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class IsAliveController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {    
        return "I'm alive";
    }
}
```

Now when you call `https://localhost:44361/isalive` you will receive the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The template I choose (using Visual studio 2019)  was:

> Asp.net core web app > Web Application

The startup file in this template is missing a line that I needed to add:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        //Add this line
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

After adding that line the endpoint works without any changes to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your problem:

#1 Your controller Name is IsAlive and you have added a route attribute on your action method as isAlive, so this would work only if you call using this Url

```
https://localhost:44361/isalive/isalive
```

#2 Remove the Route attribute from the action method

```
public class IsAliveController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        return "I'm alive";
    }
}
```

and you will be able to access using Url

```
https://localhost:44361/isalive
```